# Sails: Exclude directory from being auto loaded as helper

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am building a Sails.js application using sails 1.2.3, node 10.15. I want to include a javascript module in my api/helpers/* directory, without sails automatically using it to try to create a helper. I.e. I have javascript objects that use helpers and are used in a helper, but are not helpers themselves; as in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBkId.png), where the module 'rules' is imported into the create-rule helper and the objects exported by this module are used within the helper.

By default, sails tries to load each file in the helpers/* directory as a helper, and throws if the underlying implementation does not match that of a valid helper:

```
ImplementationError: Failed to load helper `create-rule/rules/foo/index` into a Callable!  Sorry, could not interpret "index" because its underlying implementation has a problem:
------------------------------------------------------
• Missing the `fn` property.
------------------------------------------------------
```

Hoping someone can help out! Let me know if more info is needed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. In my humble opinion I would grab all object constructors and placed them as a single file in api/services. That will make it automatically available in all controllers. I would not allow my object's methods to use helpers by them selves (I even think you can't, at least easily). Then when you need a helper to use your object, just pass it as parameter. Anyway, again, in my humble opinion; you are structuring your code to fit all inside /helpers and that will make it extremely hard to develop. Let assume you manage to make it work all inside /helpers, only you without exception, will be able to understand what it does or how it works. Doesn't seem as a good idea.

Comment: Thank you, this is essentially the solution I came up with as well. 

You can access sails helpers anywhere you have access to the global sails object ( i.e. sails.helpers.{{helperName}} ).

Thanks for taking the time to answer!!